# Android WebView Screen Goes black during load the next or same page

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-manifest

We made an android application for samsung galaxy tab using webview but when we hit the same page or a different page in between we got a black screen for 4-5 seconds after that screen shows the page.
So please tell me what we do for this i don't want that black screen.
Kindly find the below code for the same.

**CallKiosk.java**

```
package one97.kiosk;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class CallKiosk extends Activity {
    public final String url = "http://10.0.8.178:8088/Kiosk/";
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        WebView webview = new WebView(this);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        setContentView(webview); 
        webview.loadUrl(url); 
    }
    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />

<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="one97.kiosk"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/logo" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".CallKiosk"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: I suppose the page is loading during this black screen. Just show progress dialog and wait for the page to be loaded :)

Comment: Try this if useful, webvieew.setBackgroundColor("#FFFFFF");

Answer (score 1):

Try this if useful, webvieew.setBackgroundColor("#FFFFFF")